# include_path gets ignored? Or

Tags: php, include-path

Recently my ISP added imap functionality to my webserver. After the installation they recompiled PHP. But the hostingclients on my server are including from a specific hostingaccount on the server. By adding an extra include_path to the CMS folder the websites are able to communicate with the CMS and database. The strange thing is that after recompiling PHP the 'client-accounts' can't include my CMS files anymore. I'm prompted with the traditional error 'failed to open stream'.

I've tried to add the includepath in the php.ini, but as i expected without any result. Do you have any idea why the include_path is getting ignored/excluded/overruled? Are there perhaps other settings in php.ini which need to be set?

P.s. my server is configured without suPHP (I've been told by my ISP).

Comment: Hard to answer without hard data. What does a `echo get_include_path();` return? Can you show an isolated example of something you are trying to include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved by the ISP now. Open basedir restrections were the problem. I turned them off and now it works again :)